# How is Hibernate Database Independent?

Tags: hibernate

Have been asked recently in one of my interview. Can some one explain in detail why is Hibernate database idependent ?

Regards,
Yrus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database independency means writing no code dependent to the database vendor. Hibernate, or in general JPA, prevents you from writing code according to the Oracle specifications or MySQL specifications.

You use JPA classes and interfaces and make JPA implementation(like Hibernate or Toplink) do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is database independent because you need not change the HQL queries when you change the databases like MySQL, oracle, etc. It is achieved by using a dialect to communicate with the database. The database can be specified using dialect in the Hibernate configuration.